A way to set time on Android phone with unaccessible settings through ADB or another way?
I'm trying to set the time on an Android phone with inaccessible date & time settings, and the automatic date and time is on along with the GPS.
I've read most of the threads here and on other sites around the web, but couldn't find a solution. I tried all the ADB commands, and some work, but the commands to change time require permission (I assume root) that the phone doesn't have. I was also thinking if this is possible through a local NTP server as the phone doesn't has any network connectivity in any way (Ethernet, SIM/data, wireless).
I was thinking if this is possible and if someone could help.

Is the date & time settings inaccessible by design or by a defect/bug? Have you tried to open the settings date & time page via adb? Have you tried to provide an NTP server in your local network and announce it via DHCP?

It's unaccessible by design, and whenever I tried adb toybox it's returning that I need privileges (assume root). I was wondering exactly is this possible and if possible to have some advice on how to announce the NTP via DHCP. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
